# PHP API get authentication

Tags: php, ajax, api

I created my own API with PHP.
Now I would like to make the API more secure.

I tried to call the API with ajax:

```
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("username:password"),
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
```

and then to read in the API:

```
$_SERVER
```

but there is no Authorization in the header.

What is the easiest way to make my PHP API more secure?

Comment: How exactly do you want to authenticate users? MySQL? HTTP Auth?

Comment: I would like to check a password via MySQL.

Comment: I would suggest using POST. How is your API accessed currently?

Comment: $.ajax({
       url: 'api.php',
       data: {'function': 'test',
              'param': 'test'},
       type: 'GET',
       headers: {
       "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("test")
       },
       success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
       }
});

Comment: Are you going to use login+password for every http request?

Comment: So these headers will be passed to your Web Server. like you said, they can appear in `$_SERVER`. If you're using Apache you can setup the .htaccess to handle this. Not tried to handle this type of request in PHP myself.

Comment: Yes, I planed to use it like this: "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("username:password"),

Comment: Take a look at the 3rd example here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php I think that will get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments at http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php there is a simple auth script. Should be able to modify it for use with MySQL DB.

```
<?php

if(isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])){
     $user = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
     $pass = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];
} elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])) {
     if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']),'basic')===0){
         list($user,$pass) = explode(':', base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 6)));
     }
} else {
     header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
     header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
     die ("Not authorized");
}
// Connect to MySQL Data Source
// Perform MySQL Query - SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND PASSWORD = ?

if(!$results){
  // Close MySQL connection
  header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
  header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
  die ("Not authorized");
}

// Continue providing API Results

?>
```

If you're still not seeing results, what do you see when you `var_export` `$_SERVER`, `$_POST`, and `$_REQUEST`? What does your AJAX call pass when you POST?

Edited with more details from http://evertpot.com/223/

Comment: In my AJAX request I have this in my header: Authorization:Basic dGVzdA== 
But in my API I cant find anything like this in $_SERVER, $_POST is null and $_REQUEST only containing the data.

Comment: Usually you use a `name:pass` combo. I found this that explains things in much more depth: http://evertpot.com/223/ all I see in yours is 'test'. Did you try 'test:test' ?